# sPython Selenium: Assert regex matches string on page

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I'm trying to assert string on page is 4 alphanumeric characters + ".com.pl"

```
Assert.equal("/^[^\w]{4}$/"+".com.pl", text_on_page())
```

the error i get is:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\unittestzero.py", line 55, in equal
    assert first == second, msg
AssertionError: None
```

Should I use Assert.equal method?

I was also trying

```
Assert.true(text_on_page().matches("/^[^\w]{4}$/"+".com.pl"))
```

but i get:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'matches'
```

Comment: A regex for *4 alphanumeric characters + ".com.pl"* is `r"^\w{4}\.com\.pl$"`. It will match the whole string like `site.com.pl`.

Comment: The syntax with regex match is not right. You could use: `re.match(pattern, string)`.

Answer (score 1):

the answer seems to be

```
Assert.true(re.compile(r"^\w{4}\.com\.pl$").match(text_on_page()))
```